# Is encapsulation violated, if I use a global variable in a class member function's definition?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I've been asked to explain what encapsulation is and I replied "bundling of data and functions that modify this data, is called encapsulation."

The answer was followed by another question—"So, by your definition if I modify a global variable from a member function of a class then the encapsulation is violated."

It made sense to answer YES.

I am not sure whether my explanation is wrong or following question is valid and my answer to it as YES is correct.

Can somebody help.

Comment: That seems like a violation of encapsulation to me. The global variable is not encapsulated.

Comment: It depends, but generally using a global non-`const` variable breaks encapsulation. As I see it there is no absolutely clear answer because the concepts are fuzzy and it all depends on the situation at hand. This is one part of programming that can't be reduced to simple rules, but requires general intelligence and engineering gut-feeling.

Comment: I'd vote to close as too broad, except that I can imagine that some people may use an interpretation where there *is* some definite clear answer. :)

Comment: I'd say it's a matter of opinion, myself. But if the question was asked during an interview, the goal would have been to see if you could intelligently discuss the question, not whether you came up with the "correct" binary answer.

Comment: Some error codes (for example from system APIs) are global variables, I wouldn'y say that using `::GetLastError()` from win api breaks encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)):

> In programming languages, encapsulation is used to refer to one of two
>   related but distinct notions, and sometimes to the combination
>   thereof:
>
> - A language mechanism for restricting access to some of the object's components.
> - A language construct that facilitates the bundling of data with the methods (or other functions) operating on that data

In my humble opinion the answer to the follow up question is subjective and it depends on the interpretation of the notion of encapsulation.

For example it's not a violation if the encapsulating data are limited to be the member variables of classes. A global variable that doesn't belong to an object is accessible by everyone and thus, accessing it via a member function doesn't consist any encapsulation violation.

On the other hand if you consider that encapsulation should be applied to your entire program then this global variable should have been bundled to an object and thus, raw access to it constitutes an encapsulation violation.

The bottom line is that the answer lies in the realms of theology, meaning that it depends on how encapsulation is interpreted by the different programming dogmas.

Comment: '  it's not a violation if the encapsulating data are limited to be the member variables of classes'- can you explain it with an example ?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how global variable defined and accessed.

Imagine header file containing declaration, but not definitions of member functions, and corresponding implementation file containing class members implementation.

Now consider global variable defined in this header file as internal linkage one (`static`). Or placed in unnamed namespace. It is a global variable, but functionally it does not differ from `private` `static` class member.

It is smelly code, but, I say, that variable *is* encapsulated properly: